# How to perform Associative Mining on CSV data?

Tags: python, associations, data-mining, associative

I have the following CSV data set. The data represents: A,B,C,D, and F - Entities. Column 2 is rules and the final column is rank of that entity for a particular rule.

```
A,Rule_1,1
B,Rule_1,1
C,Rule_1,2
D,Rule_1,1
E,Rule_1,2
F,Rule_1,3
A,Rule_2,3
B,Rule_2,1
C,Rule_2,2
D,Rule_2,1
E,Rule_2,2
F,Rule_2,1
```

I basically want to perform associative mining (maximum of 3 entities) with number of entities that has rule i and j rank, and create a bucket_ij. Based on this, I want to find out given the entities with rank 1, what are the entities are most likely to have rank 2. So when A, B, D = 1 then C, E = 2. How can I perform this associative mining where when certain entities have rank 1, what are the entities to have rank 2?

Comment: Great, sounds like fun. So what is your question?

Comment: @Cyber thanks for the sarcasm. I have updated the question. I basically want to find out given certain entities with rank 1, what are the entities are most likely to have rank 2.

Comment: OK, so what (if anything) have you tried so far?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is why I posted the question here to get some directions on the question. Right now, I just loaded the file and put the file contents into a list. I am not sure whether to use a dict or simple if conditions would suffice.

Comment: If you haven't started yet, I'd suggest that this would be a better fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).
First you have to name your columns on csv file:

```
Entities,Rule,Rank
A,Rule_1,1
B,Rule_1,1
C,Rule_1,2
D,Rule_1,1
E,Rule_1,2
F,Rule_1,3
A,Rule_2,3
B,Rule_2,1
C,Rule_2,2
D,Rule_2,1
E,Rule_2,2
F,Rule_2,1
```

Then save it somewhere.

```
import pandas

pathToCsvFile = 'C:\\file.csv' #for example

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(pathToCsvFile,index_col=None)
df.groupby(('Entities','Rank')).count()
```

I think with this you can get what you want. It will count how many times each entity had rank.
Output:

```
Entities  Rank
A         1       1
          3       1
B         1       2
C         2       2
D         1       2
E         2       2
F         1       1
          3       1
```

Or:

```
from scipy import stats
df.groupby(('Entities')).agg(lambda x:stats.mode(x)[0]).Rank
```

Will get the mode for each entity.
Outputs:

```
Entities
A           1
B           1
C           2
D           1
E           2
F           1
```